# Upload & Check DSYM on fabric (Crashlytics-Android)

Tags: crashlytics-android

I recently used Crashlytics to crash monitor an Android application.
All crash log that reported on Fabric cannot be read (all missing, unknown). I suspect that the DSYM file isn't uploaded correctly.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to check on Fabric that the DSYM file is missing?
2. A recommended way to upload DSYM file to fabric?
3. Can the DSYM file re-uploaded again on the same version build? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still experiencing the issue ? Here is the link to fabric doc on dSYM "[All about Missing dSYMs](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html?highlight=dsym#all-about-missing-dsyms)". Answer to you questions;

1. Is there a way to check on Fabric that the DSYM file is missing?

Missing DSYM information can be found under "fabric.io > settings > apps > "app in question > Missing DSYMs tab. That tab will have Optional and required missing DSYM UUID display there.

2. A recommended way to upload DSYM file to fabric?

Check out the link I shared above.

3. Can the DSYM file re-uploaded again on the same version build? and how?

Only time dSYm will be generated when you have made any significant changes to the code.